# What is the standard way to get an item at position x from an observable

Tags: java, rx-java

I need to access a specific item from an observable, using its position. Is following piece of code a correct way to do this?

```
observable.elementAt(position).toBlocking().first()
```

Comment: Looking at the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/elementat.html) and the [Javadoc](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/rx/Observable.html#elementAt(int)), I'd say yes. That's correct. Do you have any reason to believe it's not correct? If so, please explain what's happening.

Comment: @4castle I think it is very long code for a very simple demand!!

Comment: @a.toraby Observables are not `Collection` s; they're a much more complex concept with an API that decomposes the problem domain into simple chainable primitives.

Comment: Yes, `elementAt()` is for that but why are you blocking for it instead of reacting when that element becomes available?